# Getting all revisions of an entity with EntityFieldQuery

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, database

I'm trying to get all revisions of an entity with EntityFieldQuery.

Here's my code:

```
function entity_hash_queue($entity_restrict = NULL) {
  if ($entity_restrict) {
    $entity_info = entity_get_info($entity_restrict);
    if ($entity_info['entity keys']['revision'] != NULL) {
      $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
      $query->entityCondition('entity_type', $entity_restrict);
      $results = $query->execute();
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what property of the EntityFieldQuery object I can use to ensure that it gets every revision of an entity (if that entity supports revisions).

I'm getting a list of all entity objects, but not each revision for each object. How do I go about getting that information? I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, use db_select instead EntityFieldQuery to get all revisions from the revision table:

```
$result = db_select('your_entity_revision_table', 'yert')
    ->fields('yert')
    ->condition('entity_id', {your Entity ID})
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAllAssoc('revision_id');

kpr($result);
```